# Pygame cross platform color inconsistency

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to use `get_at` and `set_at` to change the colors of an GIF image by looking for non-transparent pixels and changing them to a desired color.

On OSX machines it's working fine, the transparent colors are read as `(0, 0, 0, 0)` and being re-colored to whatever I choose. But when I run on a Windows 7 machine the transparent pixels are read as `(255, 255, 255, 0)`, causing the whole image to be colored.

The code I'm using is as follows:

```
player_border_w, player_border_h = thisGame.ready_border.get_size()
for y in range(player_border_h):  # run for each image pixel
    for x in range(player_border_w):
        if thisGame.ready_border.get_at((x, y)) != TRANSPARENT:  # (0, 0, 0, 0)
            thisGame.ready_border.set_at((x, y), thisGame.ghost_colors[idx - 1])  # replace with desired color
```

Anyone might know what can cause this and any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour notation RGBA should give you a clue - (Red, Blue, Green, Alpha). As such, the alpha channel represents opacity - if it's set to 0, then it doesn't matter what the other colours are set to.

so you should use a method like

```
def is_transparent(colour):
    red, green, blue, alpha = colour
    if alpha == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

or, more concisely:

```
def is_transparent(colour):
    return colour[3] == 0
```

As for why this is different on OSX vs Windows, I would *guess* that either the underlying image-reading library is completely different, or that differences in the compiler used for that library between the two OS's causes the difference.

Comment: Yes, I thought that the problem was more complicated but just checking if the color has a `0` for alpha solves it in a pretty straight forward way and the reason for this problem ends up not even mattering that much.

Thanks for the help!